# How to save video data in a vector using ffmpeg? (C++)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-compression

I'm new to ffmpeg and I am trying to write a program for video editing.

I want to import a video file and save it somehow in a vector so I could edit its frames later.
When I saved all the decoded AVFrames in a vector I saw it takes a lot of memory and that I need to find a better way to do so.

The function I used for reading a video:

** the function is in a class that representing video, `source` type is `std::vector<AVFrame>`

```
void VideoSource::ReadSource(std::string path)
{
    // Open the file using libavformat
    AVFormatContext* av_format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!av_format_ctx) {
        printf("Couldn't create AVFormatContext\n");
        return; 
    }
    if (avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, path.c_str(), NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Couldn't open video file\n");
        return;
    }

    // Find the first valid video stream inside the file
    int video_stream_index = -1;
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_params = NULL;
    const AVCodec* av_codec = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < av_format_ctx->nb_streams; i)
    {
        av_codec_params = av_format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar;
        av_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(av_codec_params->codec_id);

        if (!av_codec) {
            continue;
        }
        if (av_codec_params->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            video_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (video_stream_index == -1) {
        printf("Couldn't find valid video stream inside file\n");
        return;
    }

    // Set up a codec context for the decoder
    AVCodecContext* av_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec);
    if (!av_codec_ctx) {
        printf("Couldn't create AVCpdecContext\n");
        return;
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_codec_ctx, av_codec_params) < 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't initialize AVCodecContext\n");
        return;
    }
    if (avcodec_open2(av_codec_ctx, av_codec, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't open codec\n");
        return;
    }

    AVFrame* av_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!av_frame) {
        printf("Couldn't allocate AVFrame\n");
        return;
    }
    AVPacket* av_packet = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!av_packet) {
        printf("Couldn't allocate AVPacket\n");
        return;
    }
    int response;

    while (av_read_frame(av_format_ctx, av_packet) >= 0) {
        if (av_packet->stream_index != video_stream_index) {
            av_packet_unref(av_packet);
            continue;
        }
        response = avcodec_send_packet(av_codec_ctx, av_packet);
        if (response < 0) {
            printf("Failed to decode packet: %s\n", av_err2str(response));
            return;
        }
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(av_codec_ctx, av_frame);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
            av_packet_unref(av_packet);
            continue;
        }
        else if (response < 0) {
            printf("Failed to decode frame: %s\n", av_err2str(response));
            return;
        }
        av_packet_unref(av_packet);

        av_packet = av_packet_alloc();

        // response = avcodec_send_frame(av_codec_ctx, av_frame);

        source.push_back(*new AVFrame);
        source.back() = *av_frame_clone(av_frame);

        av_frame_unref(av_frame);
    }
    

    avformat_close_input(&av_format_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(av_format_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&av_frame);
    av_packet_free(&av_packet);
    avcodec_free_context(&av_codec_ctx);
}
```

I thought maybe I should save it as a vector of encoded AVFrames or as a vector of encoded packet that contains some frames in it.

When I tried to encode a single AVFrame, I added this line
`response = avcodec_send_frame(av_codec_ctx, av_frame);` before pushing the frame into the vector (You can see it marked as a comment in the code above).
It returned invalid argument (-22) and I am not sure why.

**Questions:**

1. Why did I get that error (-22)?
2. How to save an encoded packet with multiple AVFrame in it?
3. Is there a better way of working on a video that won't take as much memory?

Comment: Video formats are streaming formats, they usually store incremental differences between frames rather than each frame as a complete snapshot. If you transform a video into a series of standalone frames it will result in a larger file than the video stream (i.e. compressed) format.

Comment: I understand this concept but how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

##### 1. Why did I get that error (-22)?

The error (-22) means `EINVAL`, or ***Invalid argument*** in FFmpeg.
You passed decode codec context to `avcodec_send_frame()`, but `avcodec_send_frame()` expects encode codec context as its input. That's why such error was returned.

##### 2. How to save an encoded packet with multiple AVFrame in it?

I don't get what you mean precisely. Both AVPacket and AVFrame can be saved if you pay enough attention to the fact that they are reference counted in normal cases. In that aspect, however, there are several suspicious points in your code.

##### 3. Is there a better way of working on a video that won't take as much memory?

If you are experiencing a linear increase in memory usage over time, it is because a memory leak is occurring. If not, you can just simply reduce the amount of frames to save.